# Userform pops up if cell contains "2SO" or "2SQ"

Tags: excel, vba, module, userform

I am trying to get a User form to appear if a cell in my spread sheet states either "2SQ" or "2SO" - both require the same User form. There is one text field on the User Form for the user to either input a number for example "0001" or a word such as "Various". Once the User enters in the data, there is an "OK" Command Button (CommandButton1) to press. I then want the data they put in the User form to go into another cell of the spread sheet.

I have already created the User form (UserForm1) however cannot get it to appear when require and obviously, I can't get it to transfer the data entered into another cell.

I would love to give you examples of what I have already tried however they are just copy and pastes from websites to try and make it happen with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try some VBA likme this in the Worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Target.cells(1, 1).Value
        Case "2SQ", "2SO"
            UserForm1.Show Modal:=True
            Sheet.CellWhereYouWantItToGo.Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
    End Select
End Sub
```

The Modal part means the code will wait until the form is closed (i.e. in your ComandButton1 click event you must Me.Hide)